# Multiple widget instances - need to update each instance separately

Tags: java, android, widget, multiple-instances

I created simple example widget and simple configuration activity for it. I need to invoke configuration activity for each widget instance after user clicks on widets. Each instance should have separate settings and after click, configuration activity should be filled with settings got from this specific instance used to invoke config dialog, allowing to change settings for this specific instance only (other existing widget instanced should stay untouched).

So, my widget code:

```
package com.example.michal.widgettest2;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 * App Widget Configuration implemented in {@link MyWidgetConfigureActivity MyWidgetConfigureActivity}
 */
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.my_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            MyWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId)
    {
        CharSequence widgetText = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
}
```

My config activity code:

```
package com.example.michal.widgettest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * The configuration screen for the {@link MyWidget MyWidget} AppWidget.
 */
public class MyWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity
{

    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    EditText mAppWidgetText;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.michal.widgettest2.MyWidget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";

    public MyWidgetConfigureActivity()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
       setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_widget_configure);
        mAppWidgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
        {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mAppWidgetText.setText(loadTitlePref(MyWidgetConfigureActivity.this, mAppWidgetId));
    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final Context context = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

            // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
            String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
            saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            MyWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        prefs.commit();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null)
        {
            return titleValue;
        } else
        {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
        prefs.commit();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work as should. The settings displayed on configuration activity are not from widget that was used to invoke config activity and update goes to incorrect widget instance.

Probably I have ommited something, can you provide any tips what's wrong?

[edit]
Updated code:

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
            //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = getUniquePI(context,null,appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.my_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }


static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId)
    {
        CharSequence widgetText = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);


        //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getUniquePI(context,null,appWidgetId);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
```

Now my widget does not respond to click events (config activity is not showing). What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below sample step by step.

Step 1

Create Service UpdateWidgetService.java

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
    public UpdateWidgetService() {
    }
    public static final String SKIP = "skip";
    public static final String OPENAPP = "openapp";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent pIntent, int flags, int startId) {

        String command = pIntent.getAction();

        int appWidgetId = pIntent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            if(command.equals(SKIP)){
                /**Do the SKIP click work here*/
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }else if(command.equals(OPENAPP)){
             /**Do the OPENAPP click work here*/
                Intent mAct=new Intent(this, OPENAPP.class);
                mAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(mAct);
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }

            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.widet_ibtn_skip, "MyTextHere");
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_tv_title, "Title");

            remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widet_ibtn_skip,WallWidgetProvider.makeControlPendingIntent(getApplicationContext(),SKIP,appWidgetId));
            remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_tv_title,WallWidgetProvider.makeControlPendingIntent(getApplicationContext(),OPENAPP,appWidgetId));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);


        return super.onStartCommand(pIntent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Step 2
Create WidgetProvider as WallWidgetProvider.java

```
public class WallWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{

    public static final int UPDATE_RATE = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            setCounterAlarm(context, appWidgetId, -1);
        }
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context,UpdateWidgetService.class));
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        PrefrenceSettings ps=new PrefrenceSettings(context);

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                setCounterAlarm(context, appWidgetId, UPDATE_RATE);
            }

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    public static void setCounterAlarm(Context context, int appWidgetId, int updateRate) {
        PendingIntent newPending = makeControlPendingIntent(context,UpdateWidgetService.UPDATE,appWidgetId);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (updateRate >= 0) {
            alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), updateRate, newPending);
        } else {
            // on a negative updateRate stop the refreshing
            alarms.cancel(newPending);
        }
    }

    public static PendingIntent makeControlPendingIntent(Context context, String command, int appWidgetId) {
        Intent active = new Intent(context,UpdateWidgetService.class);
        active.setAction(command);
        active.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        //this Uri data is to make the PendingIntent unique, so it wont be updated by FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        //so if there are multiple widget instances they wont override each other
        Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("widget://widget/id/#"+command+appWidgetId), String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
        active.setData(data);
        return(PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, active, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }

}
```

Hope you should know how to use these two class in your project, These classes generate unique identification of each Widget.

Comment: Call above code like, Don't Pass null in command

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = getUniquePI(context,"cmdClick",appWidgetId);

Comment: I'm not sure what should I put as "action"? I tried "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" but it does not help, still no response to click event

Comment: @user1209216 This is because "MyWidget://widget/id/#"+command+appWidgetId using command or click on the above link as i mentioned in heading line of my answer that explained with sample project. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I look into your sample on githbub, but it's still not clear for me. Can you describe "action" meaning here? I can see you are using some actions like "increase tens" etc, but I can't see where are they declared and how are they used? I don't understand how it works so I have no idea what should I put there in my case.